Rigify: Why is FK not working on the mesh but IK is working well
I'm using the generated rig from Rigify, weight paint is done, parenting is done, everything is working fine except the hand.L. It can only deform when I'm using the IK bones and IK set to 1, but if I want to use the FK bones to deform and set the FK to 1, it does not work.
The .Blend file:

FK Not working:

IK is working well:


In the screenshot you seem to have the same bone selected all the time. You have a set of IK bones and another set of FK bones, you don't use the same depending on whether your limb is using IK or FK. Also, Rigify's rig doesn't look like this by default, have you modified it in some way?

They are not the same bone, the color are different, and I just change the shape of the rig, the whole arm is using FK included the upperarm, forearm and hand and they are working well except the hand part.

For your character mesh Vertex Groups, do you see a group named after the hand-FK bone?  And if not, does the hand-FK bone have it's Deform property enabled?

I think it would be easier if you just share your file with us so that we can check the rig ourselves.

Im using the DEF collection, both right and left hand is using the DEF-hand.L and DEF-hand.R with different weight paint and these 2 bones is enabled in Deform, but hand_fk.L and hand_fk.R is not enabled in Deform, however the right hand is working well with both of the FK and IK of the rig, but the left hand is only IK is working

Agree with @L0Lock: this becomes a guessing game otherwise.  Also,, IK bones should always have mesh deform turned off.

Hello, user186459, welcome. This one really does need a share on https://blend-exchange.com/ to avoid a guessing-game. Please follow the instructions there, and edit the provided link into your post. Then we can re-open for you, and be of as much  help as we can, without taking shots in the dark. Thanks.
